# How to handle push notification when site is already open?

Tags: javascript, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am making a site in JavaScript. It uses Firebase push-notifications. I get notifications when the site is closed, or it's on a different tab. However, I want to receive notifications even if the site is already open, or do something when it receives a notification. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are deploying your application using GCP, you need to change edit your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` using editor.

Here is a [lab](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/firebase-web#10) that could help you; this [information](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging) could help you